# Best way to parse this string?

Tags: javascript, python, html

> data:
>   {\"id\":123,\"channel\":\"private_A25BHd\",\"text\":{\"content\":\"{\\"m\\":\\"event\\",\\"p\\":{\\"id\\":123123123,\\"aid\\":125123123,\\"sym\\":\\"BITMEX:XBTUSD\\",\\"res\\":\\"1\\",\\"desc\\":\\"test
>   message on line1\\ntest message on
>   line2\\",\\"snd\\":false,\\"snd_file\\":\\"alert\/fired\\",\\"snd_duration\\":0.0,\\"popup\\":true,\\"fire_time\\":123123,\\"bar_time\\":123123,\\"cross_int\\":true}}\",\"channel\":\"alert\"}}

It unfortunately comes in as a string, though I'd like it to change into a dict if possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well json.dumps wouldnt work, havent had much experience outside of that sadly. actually skip that json loads work.

Comment: 'comes in' to where? The HTML client page or the server ? Show more workings and perhaps we can help.

Comment: Looks like overencoded JSON. It has should be fixed at the source. Most likely at the source already encoded JSON is added to a structure that is then encoded as JSON again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `json.loads()` which parse the string in to JSON object(Python dictionary) by importing the `json` library.

**Code :**

```
import json

json_string = '{\"id\":123,\"channel\":\"private_A25BHd\",\"text\":{\"content\":\"{\\"m\\":\\"event\\",\\"p\\":{\\"id\\":123123123,\\"aid\\":125123123,\\"sym\\":\\"BITMEX:XBTUSD\\",\\"res\\":\\"1\\",\\"desc\\":\\"test message on line1\\ntest message on line2\\",\\"snd\\":false,\\"snd_file\\":\\"alert\/fired\\",\\"snd_duration\\":0.0,\\"popup\\":true,\\"fire_time\\":123123,\\"bar_time\\":123123,\\"cross_int\\":true}}\",\"channel\":\"alert\"}}'

parsed_string = json.loads(json_string)
print(parsed_string)
```

**Output :**

```
{'text': {'channel': 'alert', 'content': '{"m":"event","p":{"id":123123123,"aid":125123123,"sym":"BITMEX:XBTUSD","res":
"1","desc":"test message on line1\ntest message on line2","snd":false,"snd_file":"alert/fired","snd_duration":0.0,"popu
p":true,"fire_time":123123,"bar_time":123123,"cross_int":true}}'}, 'channel': 'private_A25BHd', 'id': 123}
```

& if you want to simply print any specific value, you can use

```
print(parsed_string["id"])
```

it prints the `id` value which is `123`

Answer (score 3):

use json library in python

```
import json

json.loads(your_string)
```